# Access Shares from a Company on LinkedIn via PHP from Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, linkedin-api

I am trying to retrieve the shares of a company on linkedIn (basically just read the stream, as is easily possible on twitter) to display them on a Wordpress website in a custom HTML/CSS styling, so I only need the data. This should happen just in the backend, so no user interaction (as login etc.) should be necessary.[The end result is simply a slider that aggregates the latest social media posts, like twitter, facebook & linkedin. Works for Twitter & FB so far.]

After many hours of research it seems to me that this is not directly possible with an entirely server-side solution?

Can someone direct me if it is possible to do so? There are many php linkedin libs, but all of them seem to direct to some sort of login from which the user is redirected back? (maybe I am mistaken here).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look if they offer public rss feeds, thats the most simple way. When they offer only protected then search for developer acces from where you can get api access.